# Missing display option in dashlet

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, contribution-page, recurring-contributions

I am not able to see any display option in civiCRM 4.6.10 Version of Joomla to show report on dashlet in bar/pie format under **access** tab in report instance. Please help from where i can activate the bar/pie option. I am getting tabular report when i check option

**Available for Dashboard?      Users with appropriate permissions can add this report to their dashboard.**

Answer (score 3):

The option you're looking for isn't under the Access tab.  It's below all the tab data.  See the attached screenshot.

Note that most reports do NOT offer the ability to view a chart - make sure your report does!  If you'd like to test, use the "Contribution Summary" report, which supports charts.

After you've changed the view, press the "Update Report" button, and on the dashboard, press "Refresh Dashboard Data" and you should be in business.

[image]